# -HTML- Items wont align horizontally

Tags: html, inline

I'm trying to make a navigation bar at the top of my site. But the items wont align horizontally properly. I used display: inline. That should make things align side by side right? Well... Once I set display to inline, the width of the item seems to be set to 100%, so the items are not allowed to go side by side. When I set the display to inline-block, the height seems to triple, but is the items are set side by side. Though, I don't want it to be higher than it is because then the appearance isn't what I want.

How can I make the items align properly!? Please help and thank you if you do.

---

html code

---

```
<div id="Bars">
        <ul>
            <li><p style="width: 50px">Home</p></li>
            <li><p style="width: 73px">Software</p></li>
            <li><p style="width: 62px">Gallery</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

---

css code

---

```
#Bars{
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000099;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#Bars ul li p{
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#Bars ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below css to your style sheet and set `inline-block` to `li`, in your case predefined `margin` and `padding` are applying

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#Bars ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eavv8xst/)

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
  <li class="current_page_item">[LINK]</li>
  <li class="page_item">[LINK]</li>
  <li class="page_item">[LINK]</li>
  <li class="page_item">[LINK]</li>
  <li class="page_item">[LINK]</li>
  <li class="page_item">[LINK]</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 height:16px;
 background: #ccc
}
#nav ul li {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
#nav {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use can use display: inline-block; and need to adjust the margin.
js fiddle link :

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/2pr2pq78/`
```